# Cannot connect to ActiveMQ "Classic"

Tags: java, activemq-classic

We use IBM MQ for some JMS integration between some of our micro services. Because IBM MQ docker image does not run on Mac book laptops with Apple M1 processor we configured our applications requiring JMS integration to be able to run against ActiveMQ broker as well.

We use the latest version of ActiveMQ classic which is 5.17.3 and we run it as a docker container.

For most of us who tried to run against ActiveMQ everything works OK but we have a colleague that is unable to start the application because it fails to connect to the ActiveMQ broker. All we can see in the application logs is this:

```
    Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
                    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:80)
                    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1423)
                    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1488)
                    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnection.createSession(ActiveMQXAConnection.java:74)
                    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnection.createXASession(ActiveMQXAConnection.java:61)
                    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.jms.JmsTransactionalResource.refreshXAConnection(JmsTransactionalResource.java:74)
                    ... 10 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
                    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:329)
                    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:318)
                    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:94)
                    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:116)
                    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
                    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
                    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
                    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1394)
                    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Googling for `org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed` brought us some old internet posts but none of them brought any light.

Part of the ActiveMQ docker logs we can see below log entry after broker is started which makes us think the broker is started OK. Also he can access the ActiveMQ admin console when hitting http://localhost:8161/admin URL

```
INFO | Listening for connections at : tcp://somelaptopid:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
```

Comment: If you eliminate Docker from the equation and just run the broker on "bare metal" does the problem still occur?

Comment: I tried to do this already but Macbook laptop will not run the broker because `macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware` and we cannot add the security exception as we don't have admin access to our machines.

Comment: I can't really help you with that unfortunately.